# Show a number to two decimal places

Tags: php, formatting, numbers, rounding, number-formatting

What's the correct way to round a PHP string to two decimal places?

```
$number = "520"; // It's a string from a database

$formatted_number = round_to_2dp($number);

echo $formatted_number;
```

The output should be `520.00`;

How should the `round_to_2dp()` function definition be?

Comment: This really isn't "rounding". Rounding _reduces_ precision. It will not add decimal places to a number that doesn't have them. Based on many of the answers and comments, it seems like people are thinking that rounding is something it isn't. `round` is a math function, and this is just a formatting problem.

Answer (score 1488, accepted):

You can use [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format):

```
return number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

Example:

```
$foo = "105";
echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00
```

This function returns a **string**.

Comment: round() would be better for it's readability and simplicity too, but for anything critical be aware that it has been known to be buggy

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario `round` doesn't solve the OP's problem here. `round("520", 2)` returns the float `520`, and echoing that will of course not show it to 2 decimal places. For the OP's purpose - showing an integer to 2 decimal places by padding it with trailing zeroes - you need a number formatting function, not a rounding function.

Comment: All the other answers are limited to decimal values with a dot notation. When you need to get `520,00` instead of `520.00`, this simply works.

Comment: if you want to limit only float but not int then bcdiv($number,1,2)

Comment: I don't think if it's because i am using `php 7.1.0` but the float-casting seems useless in my case and adding or removing will have no effect to the end result.

Comment: I think you should use bcadd(0,$yournumber,2) it will give you perfect result.

Comment: If value is 1.255 and then we convert it so we will get 1.26 but what can we do if we want to get value 1.25 from 1.255. please let me know any trick for this.

Comment: @BhavinThummar You can use round() with mode PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN, as show Somnath's answer. If you want to round down, and always maintain 2dp, then you could use a mixture of this answer, and Somnath's to round first, and then use number_format to make sure it is output in the correct way.

Comment: if you want to avoid round up of values and keep number to 2 decimal places this will work fine `floor($number * 100) / 100;`

Comment: Also please note that this method returns a **localised number**. That means 1234.567 will be outputted as '1,234.57'. In some cases you might not want a thousands separator.

Comment: @finngu: It's a parameter of that function, as shown in the answers example at the time of your comment: https://3v4l.org/0lAiH -- "20105.045" -> 20105.05; The third parameter of https://php.net/number_format ; `$thousands_separator` .

Comment: @hakre It is shown, but not explained. I just added some additional info, because others might miss it, just as I did in the beginning. Localised numbers can be an easy to overlook mistake.

Answer (score 379):

Use [`round()`](https://www.php.net/round) (use if you are expecting a number in float format only, else use number_format() as [an answer given by Codemwnci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483561/1045444)):

```
echo round(520.34345, 2);   // 520.34
echo round(520.3, 2);       // 520.3
echo round(520, 2);         // 520
```

From the manual:

> #### Description:

```
float round(float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]]);
```

> Returns the rounded value of `val` to specified `precision` (number of digits after the decimal point). `precision` can also be negative or zero (default).

...

> #### Example #1 `round()` examples

```
<?php
    echo round(3.4);         // 3
    echo round(3.5);         // 4
    echo round(3.6);         // 4
    echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
    echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
    echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
    echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
    echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```

> ###Example #2 mode examples

```
<?php
    echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   // 10
    echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 9
    echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // 10
    echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  // 9
```

> 

```
    echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   // 9
    echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 8
    echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // 8
    echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  // 9
?>
```

Comment: @khuderm `round($number, 2);` doesn't work. I want 520.00 not 520. Can't believe round doesn't do that by default.

Comment: It doesn't even answer the OP correctly but has over 100 votes up!

Comment: I want use number format but when 100.00 will return 100. How is it?

Comment: but i need .93 if the number 123.93 @SomnathMuluk

Comment: @RobSedgwick many poeple are searching for function to trim the remaining part after 3.333333333 to be 3.33 etc.

Comment: How to return ```.00``` when the value is example 500 ? I have tried to use ```floatval()``` and ```round()``` but still get the same result. Using ```number_format``` returns strings.

Answer (score 240):

Alternatively,

```
$padded = sprintf('%0.2f', $unpadded); // 520 -> 520.00
```

Comment: So what if you want `520,00`? I guess the other answer works better in that case.

Comment: ^no the other answer will not give two decimal places for an int

Comment: other reasons you may want this is you dont want rounding... or in my cause SQL floats returned are not treated the same as normal floats which is a PHP math bug

Comment: @SPRBRN - [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) has an option to specify decimal separator character.

Comment: I tried this first but the output is converted to a string so you and I have to return it back to float again , so take care of this point

Answer (score 57):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

e.g.

```
echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05

echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
```

Comment: Round will do the exact functionality that Rich is wanting, but  number_format()  would be more interesting to look into for all kinds of numerical formatting.

Comment: This method will perform rounding as well over just forcing the digits ".00" on the end.

Comment: I'd tried round, but it doesn't work - it won't add the extra .00.

Comment: Try using one of the examples I have there, it on it's own in a PHP script. You should get the commented result. If not then you have a problem with your PHP setup somewhere.

Comment: round(520, 2) returns 520, not 520.00  as required by @Rich

Comment: Update for PHP 7.4+ since this answer is very old. Since round returns a float it can only be guaranteed to return a number with at most one decimal place (ie, it returns something that is not an integer, with the minimum number of decimal places possible to represent the number). So `round(1,2)` (or any level or precision)  returns '*1.0*', because '1.00' would not be a valid float. To make numbers behave like strings, you need to use string manipulation functions. (Previous versions of PHP may have acted differently/less logically)

Comment: @fred2 - To convert float to a string with desired format, use `sprintf` or `number_format`. Internally, a float isn't `3.0`; its simply a binary value that is at (or sometimes very close to) 3. To convert to a string that has two decimal digits: `$str = sprintf("%0.2f", $value);`

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's why I said "To make numbers behave like strings, you need to use string manipulation functions".

Comment: I was fighting with this as well until I realized this. I needed .00 output, basically money output.  The float isn't actually money data type.  In my opinion then, it makes sense to output the string value. For that I like answer from @Codemwnci best.

Answer (score 33):

Try:

```
$number = 1234545454; 
echo  $english_format_number = number_format($number, 2);
```

The output will be:

```
1,234,545,454.00
```

Comment: That works, but the output would be a string and not a number.

Comment: if you want to use number_format at least make it number_format($number, 2, '.', '')

Comment: @Ethan - correct, this Q&A is about formatting a number as a string, with a specified number of decimal digits.

Answer (score 27):

Use the PHP [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.

For example,

```
$num = 7234545423;
echo number_format($num, 2);
```

The output will be:

```
7,234,545,423.00
```

Answer (score 21):

use `round(yourValue,decimalPoint)` ([php manual’s page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php))  or `number_format(yourValue,decimalPoint);`

`number_format()` return value as string like this type **1,234.67**. so in this case you can not use it for addition or any calculation. if you try then you have to deal with **Number Format Error**...

In this case `round(121222.299000000,2)` will be better option.
The result would be **121222.29** ...

Comment: Hi @pankaj , I was wondering because using ```number_format()``` returns ```string``` how can I  change it to 0.00 without being a string? Thank you

Comment: @natsumiyu: number_format() is _for_ returning a string, if you need a floating point number use https://php.net/round , round() , which is _for_ returning a float. As written in the answer you requested feedback for in your comment, see first and last sentence, however mind comments like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places#comment4903201_4483553

Answer (score 20):

You can use the PHP `printf` or `sprintf` functions:

Example with `sprintf`:

```
$num = 2.12;
echo sprintf("%.3f", $num);
```

You can run the same without `echo` as well. Example: `sprintf("%.3f", $num);`

Output:

```
2.120
```

Alternatively, with `printf`:

```
echo printf("%.2f", $num);
```

Output:

```
2.124
```

Answer (score 16):

Here I get two decimals after the `.` (dot) using a function...

```
function truncate_number($number, $precision = 2) {

    // Zero causes issues, and no need to truncate
    if (0 == (int)$number) {
        return $number;
    }

    // Are we negative?
    $negative = $number / abs($number);

    // Cast the number to a positive to solve rounding
    $number = abs($number);

    // Calculate precision number for dividing / multiplying
    $precision = pow(10, $precision);

    // Run the math, re-applying the negative value to ensure
    // returns correctly negative / positive
    return floor( $number * $precision ) / $precision * $negative;
}
```

Results from the above function:

```
echo truncate_number(2.56789, 1); // 2.5
echo truncate_number(2.56789);    // 2.56
echo truncate_number(2.56789, 3); // 2.567

echo truncate_number(-2.56789, 1); // -2.5
echo truncate_number(-2.56789);    // -2.56
echo truncate_number(-2.56789, 3); // -2.567
```

**New Correct Answer**

Use the PHP native BC Math function [bcdiv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

```
echo bcdiv(2.56789, 1, 1);  // 2.5
echo bcdiv(2.56789, 1, 2);  // 2.56
echo bcdiv(2.56789, 1, 3);  // 2.567
echo bcdiv(-2.56789, 1, 1); // -2.5
echo bcdiv(-2.56789, 1, 2); // -2.56
echo bcdiv(-2.56789, 1, 3); // -2.567
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Works great for longitude & latitude.

Answer (score 15):

Another more exotic way to solve this issue is to use [`bcadd()`](http://php.net/manual/function.bcadd.php) with a dummy value for the $right_operand of `0`.

```
$formatted_number = bcadd($number, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Note that `bc*` functions do not round up, they always round down. For example, `bcadd("1.0999","0.0",1)` yields "1.0", not "1.1".

Comment: BC Math functions actually just stop processing at `$scale` fractional digits. This equals rounding towards zero.

Answer (score 13):

```
bcdiv($number, 1, 2) // 2 varies for digits after the decimal point
```

This will display exactly two digits after the decimal point.

**Advantage:**

If you want to display two digits after a float value only and not for int, then use this.

Comment: This is the most universal solution if you have bcdiv (it's a stock but non-default package on centos6).

Answer (score 11):

```
$retailPrice = 5.989;
echo number_format(floor($retailPrice*100)/100,2, '.', '');
```

It will return 5.98 without rounding the number.

Comment: Only this can also do the job `floor($retailPrice * 100) / 100;` no need of number format then.

Answer (score 10):

Use the PHP [number_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.

Answer (score 8):

I make my own.

```
$decimals = 2;
$number = 221.12345;
$number = $number * pow(10, $decimals);
$number = intval($number);
$number = $number / pow(10, $decimals);
```

Comment: Its nice to see some of the maths needed to do this. Although using a built in function is preferred for me. Theres no point re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Sorry, but round(), as it says, round de number, and sometimes, i do not want to round.

Comment: @joanlgr: 221.12345 you write in the example, but it's one of those numbers that don't exist for the computer and therefore some form of rounding - even you don't want it sometimes - already has been encoded by just writing this statement `$number = 221.12345` and letting PHP parse and execute it. Adding more lines of code afterwards does not change (but repeats) it. E.g. _"By definition, floating-point error cannot be eliminated, and, at best, can only be managed."_ from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation and the warning @ https://php.net/float.

Answer (score 8):

For conditional rounding off ie. show decimal where it's really needed otherwise whole number

123.56 => 12.56

123.00 => 123

```
$somenumber = 123.56;

$somenumber = round($somenumber,2);

if($somenumber == intval($somenumber))
{
    $somenumber = intval($somenumber);
}

echo $somenumber; // 123.56


$somenumber = 123.00;

$somenumber = round($somenumber,2);

if($somenumber == intval($somenumber))
{
    $somenumber = intval($somenumber);
}

echo $somenumber; // 123
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding to other answers, since number_format() will, by default, add thousands separator.

To remove this, do this:

```
$number = number_format($number, 2, ".", "");
```

Comment: is there a way that it will not return string when using ```number_format()```?

Comment: @natsumiyu: No, `number_format()` is _for_ returning a string, also in it's name: _format_. Use `round()` if you're looking for a floating point number. See as well https://php.net/float (_"Floating point numbers"_ in the PHP Manual).

Answer (score 7):

`round_to_2dp` is a user-defined function, and nothing can be done unless you posted the declaration of that function.

However, my guess is doing this: `number_format($number, 2);`

Comment: From your first paragraph, I think you've misunderstood the question. `round_to_2dp($number);` was meant as pseudocode; the OP was asking for somebody to tell him what to replace that expression with.

Answer (score 6):

```
$twoDecNum = sprintf('%0.2f', round($number, 2));
```

The rounding correctly rounds the number and the sprintf forces it to 2 decimal places if it happens to to be only 1 decimal place after rounding.

Answer (score 5):

```
$number = sprintf('%0.2f', $numbers); // 520.89898989 -> 520.89
```

This will give you 2 number after decimal.

Comment: No it won't. I don't know when this post was written but if you try it with your own example, at least on my machine :-) , it will output 520.90. Meaning, Rounding WILL occur. Be careful!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use two decimal digits in your entire project, you can define:

```
bcscale(2);
```

Then the following function will produce your desired result:

```
$myvalue = 10.165445;
echo bcadd(0, $myvalue);
// result=10.11
```

But if you don't use the bcscale function, you need to write the code as follows to get your desired result.

```
$myvalue = 10.165445;
echo bcadd(0, $myvalue, 2);
// result=10.11
```

To know more

- *[BC Math Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)*
- *[bcscale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php)*

Answer (score 2):

Number without round

```
$double = '21.188624';
echo intval($double) . '.' . substr(end(explode('.', $double)), 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) and [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$num = 520.00
strtok(round($num, 2), '.') . '.' . str_pad(strtok('.'), 2, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

- Choose the number of decimals
- Format commas(,)
- An option to trim trailing zeros

> Once and for all!

```
function format_number($number,$dec=0,$trim=false){
  if($trim){
    $parts = explode(".",(round($number,$dec) * 1));
    $dec = isset($parts[1]) ? strlen($parts[1]) : 0;
  }
  $formatted = number_format($number,$dec); 
  return $formatted;
}
```

Examples

```
echo format_number(1234.5,2,true); //returns 1,234.5
echo format_number(1234.5,2);      //returns 1,234.50
echo format_number(1234.5);        //returns 1,235
```

Comment: Hi @Kareem , I was wondering how can I return the decimal format not being a string? I tried your code but the return is a string. Thank you

Comment: Hi @natsumiyu, you can simply declare the variable type depending on your use case. If you always need a number to be return you can edit the function to declare (int) there on the returned string.


     *$num = (int) format_number(1234.5,2);*

Answer (score 0):

That's the same question I came across today and want to round a number and return float value up to a given decimal place and it must not be string (as returned from number_format)
the answer is

`printf('%.' . $decimalPlaces . 'f', round($number, $decimalPlaces));`

thanks to mickmackusa for indicating the mistake

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an antipattern.  It is more sensibly written as `printf()` only.

Comment: I tried to use this but I still get a string value.

Comment: sprintf() will never return float value, so it's really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Either way, both round() and sprintf() are featured in the existing answers, so I don't find this one adding anything new.