# How can I set default input value to 0.00 in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

How can I format an input number to be 0.00 if it has not any value? I tried (double) but it prints 0 only.

Comment: Input to what? Database or display?  [`number_format()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is used to format for display.

Comment: input type =text :) just for front end input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
echo number_format($var,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to print specific no. of decimal points, use `number_format`.

```
  $float_var = number_format($var, 2);
```

Comment: Casting to float won't help.  If `$var` has no value, at best you'll get `0`.  Not `0.00`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

This forces 2 points after the decimal, sets the decimal as a period. You can also forego the last two as it defaults to it;

Note: The third value is your decimal separator, the fourth value is the thousandths separator.

```
$var = number_format($number, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to format the value i sugest you to use meioMask pluging.
So you define your field as number and the pluging do the trick, even if you set "0" for the value

Answer (score 0):

For direct output:

```
  printf('%0.2f',$var);
```

Output into variable:

```
  $outVar = sprintf('%0.2f',$var);
```

This statemant casts $var type to float and prints with 2 decimal signs

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should check it first if the value is not set

```
if(!isset($variableName))
{
   // then set
   $variableName = "0.00"; // => string

   //or like this
   $variableName = number_format(0,2); // => this result is also string
}
echo "value: ",$variableName;
```

result

```
0.00
```