# Using double/float in php

Tags: php, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

```
$b = $del['Antal'];
$y = $info['Pris'];
$z = $y * $b;
```

$y comes from a mysql database where its type is "double(10,2)" so that one works when I try echo $y; it responds with two decimals.

But now I would like to multiply it with $b.

For example 
10.20 * 2 = 20.40

But right now it is like:
10.20 * 2 = 20.4 (only one decimal)

I want two decimals, what to do? I tried some stuff with the (double) function, but didn't really work out. What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) :

```
$b = $del['Antal'];
$y = $info['Pris'];
$z = number_format($y * $b ,2);
```

The `number_format` function :

```
string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )
```

And if you don't want the default format :

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

Comment: This partially works...
But
1 * 1670.10 = 1,670,10
Which is not correct :(

Comment: what does "partially" mean?

Comment: The third and fourth parameters are dec_point and thousands_sep so if you want 1670.10 you can do number_format($y * $b ,2, ".", "").

Comment: I understand that you don't want a String because you want to do more math but why you care about having 1 or 2 float number if you want to do more math... You should only care about the String that will be print at the end.

Comment: Ok I changed it to
$z = number_format($y * $b ,2, '.', '');
Just as the php manual says, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure that you store it at two decimal places by using sprintf and storing it as a string:

```
$z = sprintf('%.2f', $y * $b);
```

The `%.2f` ensure that there are always two digits after the decimal point.

Comment: This one doesn't work for me since I have to do more math with $z later. So I can't store it as a string

Comment: You can cast it back into a float.

Answer (score 2):

The data type you describe are *fixed* point numbers, not *floating* point numbers (float). PHP does not have such a data type, however it can [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) floats for you. And it seems like that is what you are looking for, formatting output.

Comment: it has a float type but it is hidden. In the most naural level of php you use scalar type, but at a lower level you do use true types. An evidence is in the functions `is_int`for example which answers `false`when you say `is_int("14")`. You can also use cast operators.
so Jean-Philippe Bond has the right answer.

Comment: @artragis you are missing my point. I said, PHP has no *fixed point* data type (like decimal(10,2) in MySQL). Of course it has floats and I don't see how that would be hidden.

Comment: oh yes you are right misread you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

```
$z = $y * floatval($b);
```

Alternatively:

```
$b = (float) $b;
```

It should automatically convert to a float, however, if you multiply it by 10.20. Read PHP's documentation on [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

---

If it's merely a styling thing:

```
$b = number_format($b, 2);
```

Comment: Casting it as a float does not ensure two decimal places. I am not the downvoter though.