# Jquery/Javascript/PHP: Display every number with two decimals

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, numbers, decimal

I have a (hopefully) quick and short question. I try to find a Javascript, Jquery, or PHP function that allows me to display every number on a webpage with two decimals. Basically, 0 should be 0.00, 1.5 should be 1.50, and 1.54 should stay 1.54.

However, most functions that I found on stackoverflow, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places) one, seem to require me to put in each number manually (and don't work for integers). Is there a way I can apply the function to a class? Ideally, I am looking for a function that (1) applies to all numbers that are within the same class and (2) displays each of those numbers with two decimals, even the integers.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: "Is there a way I can apply the function to a class?" - what kind of class? Are you talking about css class?

Comment: yep, the last paragraph about classes is absolutely unclear. Can you give an example? As for the integers: just use echo sprintf('%.2f',0);

Comment: I'm sorry that I have been unclear. I actually didn't know there were different kinds of classes. I meant a class like aoi used, so a css class I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP you have `number_format($whateverNumber,2)` or sprintf, or even simply typecasting to float might work given the data; in javascript/jquery you can use `toFixed(2)`;

In jquery you can do something like

```
$(function(){
    $(".yourClass").each(function(){
        var number = parseFloat($(this).html());
        number = isNaN(number)?0:number;
        $(this).html(number.toFixed(2));
    });
})
```

Comment: This seems to have worked like a charm!  Thank you very much, aoi!