# PHP to round up to the 2nd decimal place

Tags: php, rounding

By calculating areas I have a number which I need to display in a strange way.

Always display 2 decimal places.
Always round up the 2nd decimal place if the 3rd+ decimal places > 0.

Examples:

```
0.5 = 0.50
0.500003 = 0.51
0.96531 = 0.97
0.96231 = 0.97
0.8701 = 0.88
```

Is there a built in function to do this in PHP or do I need to write one?

Comment: [`round()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: echo round($value, 2)

Comment: multiply by 100, [`ceil()`](http://php.net/ceil), divide by 100 then format as needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use 2 functions:

- round() - docs here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php
- number_format() - docs here: https://www.php.net/number_format

I've used both with success, and depending on what you're doing with the result, you may chose either of the above functions.

Later edit: If you want to only round up, you can use ceil() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php + number format or round

```
echo round(ceil($number*100)/100,2);
```

As another user suggested earlier

Comment: Using the round function is not needed in this case as the division by 100 will format it to 2 decimal places. Ceil returns a whole integer.

Comment: the round() method will fail on a number with two decimals :
    
echo round(ceil(1.12*100)/100, 2); # output 1.13

Answer (score 11):

To always round up you will want to use something like this:

```
$number = 0.8701;

echo ceil($number*100)/100;

// = 0.88
```

Comment: ceil only rounds in + meaning 12.011 will be rounded to 12.02

Comment: Yes, if you read the OP question that is what he has asked for. Always round up to 2 decimal places.