# How to round off based on decimal number?

Tags: php

I need to round the numbers.

```
46.38 >>> 46.40
46.40 >>> 46.40
46.41 >>> 46.50
```

I am using `round($price, 1)` but this converts `46.41 to 46.40`. But i need `46.50`

Comment: If you save the original, compare it to the rounded value and then check if the rounded value is smaller just add 0.1?

Comment: So you want to round up?  Try `round($price + 0.05, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)`

Comment: @RobEyre `46.40 >>> 46.50` If its 46.40 then it needs to be 46.40

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP to round up to the 2nd decimal place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991021/php-to-round-up-to-the-2nd-decimal-place)

Comment: Basically, multiply the number up to the precision you want, call `ceil()`. then divide it back to the original exponent.

Comment: If I do `$price = 46.40; echo round($price + 0.05, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);` it gives me `46.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `ceil` instead of round, but it does not come with precision out of the box. You need to add this functionality yourself like e.g.

```
function myceil(int|float $number, int $precision, int $decimals) {
    return number_format(ceil($number*(10**$precision))/(10**$precision), 2);
}
```

You can then use it as:

```
echo myceil(46.38,1, 2).PHP_EOL;
echo myceil(46.40,1, 2).PHP_EOL;
echo myceil(46.41,1, 2).PHP_EOL;
```

This will output:

> 46.40 
> 46.40 
> 46.50

[3v4l code](https://3v4l.org/b1g0q)

Note: The `number_format` is added to additionally control the decimals that will be shown in the end. It is not (strictly speaking) necessary and also causes the function output to be a string rather than a float.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this approach:

```
$roundedPrice = round($price + 0.05, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

This produces the outputs required from the inputs given.

... or more generally, if `$precision` is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point,

```
$roundedPrice = round($price + (1/10**$precision)/2, $precision, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```