# How to Make Input Only Allow Two Decimal Places to be Entered?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, input, decimal

I am not sure how to do this, but I believe it can be done with JavaScript, or PHP. Is there anyway I can make an input that only allows 2 decimal places to be entered? Essentially, I would like the input to stop entering numbers after two decimal places, rather than give an error if five have been entered.

I am not looking for a validator, but rather an inhibitor to block anything being inputted that is more than 2 decimal places.

If anyone knows how to do this or can provide any help it will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write a trimming function

```
function trimDP(x, dp) {
    if (dp === 0)
        return Math.floor(+x).toString();
    dp = Math.pow(10, dp || 2);
    return (Math.floor((+x) * dp) / dp).toString();
}
// ex.
trimDP("1.2345"); // "1.23"
```

Next, set up this trimming function to be applied on *keypress* and *onchange* to your `<input>` e.g. by giving them the class token `dp2`

```html
<input type="text" value="0" class="dp2" />
```

```js
(function () { // do this after nodes loaded
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.dp2'), i;
    function press(e) {
        var s = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (s === '.')
            if (this.value.indexOf('.') === -1)
                return; // permit typing `.`
        this.value = trimDP(this.value + s);
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    function change() {
        this.value = trimDP(this.value);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        nodes[i].addEventListener('keypress', press);
        nodes[i].addEventListener('change', change);
    }
}());
```

You may also want to prevent non-numeric keys

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9F9Yy/7/)

Comment: Okay, I have little experience with JavaScript. How would I set this up on a simple `HTML` page?

Comment: In your demo, it does not allow any numbers after the decimal.

Comment: @Kelsey sorry, yeah I forgot the order things happen - modified the code now, please try the demo again

Comment: Thank you, it works. May I offer you a gentlemen's exchange of up votes?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a prevention then I would do it in the php as you can pretty much always find a way around preventions in javascript.

Maybe combine it with a Javascript function as well so users get formatting help and have this as a definitive prevention?

To do this in php you can use the `number_float()` function:

```
$foo = "105";

echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00
```

[PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: I need it to format while it is being inputted, not after the input has been made submitted. Thank you, though.

Comment: Okay, just remember if it's a form input then I can turn javascript off and just submit any number and it will not be prevented unless you have php validation.