# php round off value with trailing 2 decimals and multiples of 5

Tags: php

I tried this function

```
function roundUpToAny($n,$x=5) {
    return (round($n)%$x === 0) ? round($n) : round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;
}
```

`echo roundUpToAny(4.52);`         // This show 5 instead of 4.55

`echo roundUpToAny(5.1);`          // This show 5 instead of 5.10

How can i created such function

Comment: This question is about rounding - it may be useful: [4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Multiply by two, round to 1 sf, divide by two. Does it have to work for negative numbers?

Comment: @Floris as of now I will not allow negative numbers

Comment: @RyanVincent I tried the one in the link provied, If my input is 4.21 its giving 4.21 as output instead of 4.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following function does what you want:

```
function roundUpToAny($n, $x=5, $sf=2) {
  $scale = pow(10,$sf);
  return number_format(round(ceil($n*$scale / $x), $sf) * $x / $scale, $sf);
}
```

The first argument is the number to be converted, the second is the "rounding factor" (multiples of `$x` - you asked for `5` in the title of the question), the third is the number of figures after the decimal point.

Test:

```
echo roundUpToAny(1.23, 5, 2) ."\n";
echo roundUpToAny(4.54, 5, 2) ."\n";
echo roundUpToAny(5.101, 5, 3) ."\n";
echo roundUpToAny(1.19, 5, 3) ."\n";
```

Result:

```
1.25
4.55
5.105
1.190
```

**UPDATE**

You pointed out in a follow-up that the above code fails for inputs of `1.1` and `2.2`. The reason for this is the fact that these numbers [are not exactly representable in double precision (strange though this may sound)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). The following code compensates for this, by creating an intermediate value that is rounded to be an integer (and therefore can be represented exactly):

```
function roundUpToAny($n, $x=5, $sf=2) {
  $scale = pow(10,$sf);
  $temp = round($n * $scale, $sf); // get rid of small rounding errors
  return number_format(round(ceil($temp / $x), $sf) * $x / $scale, $sf);
}
```

Testing:

```
echo roundUpToAny(1.1, 5, 2) ."\n";
```

Result:

```
1.10
```

As expected.

Comment: almost ok but `roundUpToAny(1.23, 5, 2)` this results 1.2 instead 1.20

Comment: The function returns a value. Do you need it to return a string? Anyway - `roundUpToAny(1.23, 5, 2)` returns 1.25 for me...

Comment: It the function returns string what will be the output

Comment: Hi I am facing one problem with above function can you clear it