# Round Function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, workbench

I have a value of **18.5** and when I used the `round()`, it remains 18.

How to round off the value to 19.

`18.5 ---> 19` [any other functions]

Thankx

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-round-function.php

Comment: Check this link may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to refer to the ceil function. Try `ceil(18.5)`