# How to append zero after 4.5 to make it 4.50 in PHP?

Tags: php

I know it may be a silly one and it may be duplicate question as well, but I can't find any proper question posted before(may be its my incapability)

I have a value fetched from DB... its say like

```
4.5   which should be 4.500
0.01  which should be 0.010
11    which should be 11.000
```

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply format it with [`sprinft`](http://php.net/sprintf) to make it a floating point number to 2 decimal places.

```
echo sprintf("%.2f", 4.5);
```

https://eval.in/378771

If you change the `2` to a `3` you will get your format you've listed.

```
echo sprintf("%.3f", 4.5) . PHP_EOL;
echo sprintf("%.3f", 0.01) . PHP_EOL;
echo sprintf("%.3f", 11) . PHP_EOL;
```

https://eval.in/378773

Answer (score 4):

[php.net/number_format](http://php.net/number_format)

`number_format(4.5,2);`

Answer (score 3):

Use the function [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format)

Trailing zeros to the right of a decimal point is not supported in PHP. You need to format the number to string.

`$value = number_format($value,3);`

Answer (score 1):

Modern way is to use [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) which formats numbers according to set locale.

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en-US', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$fmt->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 3);
$fmt->format(1234567.891234567890000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If You use mysql then Use FORMAT function 
like SELECT FORMAT(4.5,4)

Answer (score 1):

also `str_pad(4.5,STR_PAD_RIGHT)` 
for more http://php.net/manual/zh/function.str-pad.php