# How to add dots and commas to number in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, format

I have a cell with a great number, like 650400300. I need to SELECT this number and separate to receive next format - 650,400.300. Would you mind to help me, please. Thanks in advance! I'm using PHP and MySQL.

UPDATE: Now I think the correct way to do so is to use PHP, but thank you "**hd1**" your answer is perfectly fits and works correctly with what I asked here.

UPDATE2: I don't need to add zero's to the end, but I need to split the whole number into peaces with commas and dots.

Comment: You can update your post by adding the code that you have been working on. On your current post, it will receive negative votes and might be flagged for closing.

Comment: In what language, php?

Comment: @AsConfused - OP might want to achieve this using PHP, jQuery and mysql which you might see in his/her tags.

Comment: How do you define how said number will be formatted?

Comment: Right @LoganWayne i see tags was hoping to not do all 3

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't notice - PHP with MySQl. And i didn't write jquery, have no idea why it was added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: The problem with doing it in mysql above what i mentioned in my answer is that it violates n-tier development principles of presentation layer, and makes a hefty stored proc unusable to consumers of data that doesn't want a string returned but rather a value. So then the developer has to duplicate code and remember to make changes in other procs. Which of course is overlooked until the help desk calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MySQL [format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function to do this:

```
MySQL> SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,0);
12,332
```

Comment: You are right. But what is the best way - use PHP or MySQL query for it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want php and not turning mysql into a gui tool, then

```
number_format($number)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it works. PHP is a correct way to modify data from MySQL - I agree.

Comment: Mysql needs to be shown its propers, and other concurrent users too, by not bogging it down and turning it into a report engine

Answer (score 0):

#### Note:

- First, you must fetch that data:
- Then use [substr_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) to format the number

**Code:**

```
$number = "650400300";
$number = substr_replace($number, ",", 3, 0);
$number = substr_replace($number, ".", 7,0); /* RETURNS 650,400.300 */
```

Using [number_format()](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=EN%2Ffunction.number-format.php&lang=en&scope=404quickref) to your given example (650400300) will give this result:

```
$number = number_format($number); /* 650,400,300 */
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @hd1 - But OP said turn 650400300 to 650,400.300. Not 650,400,300. Well, wrong post is confusing. *insert Jackie Chan meme here *

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with MySQL is not really nice, it is supposed to give you what is in the database. If the database holds an integer, MySQL should give you an integer.

You can do it with php, after you have fetched the data using [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format):

```
$formatted_number = number_format($number);
```

Comment: It is quite nice, see my answer.