# Round up two decimals place to next multiple to ten - PHP

Tags: php, magento

I have this question:
How can round two decimals place to next multiple to ten? Follow this example:

```
$number = 120.37
// I would like some functions or trick to transform this into 120.40
```

Is it possible in php?

Comment: see the link, that might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: `$number = 120.37;

$formatted = number_format(round($number,1), 2); echo $formatted;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
round($number * 10) / 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Working like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

use this number format

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

It will give output 120.40

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
number_format(round($number,1), 2, '.', '');
```

or just

```
round($number,1);
```

if you not need it with 2 decimals