# How to show two Decimal point

Tags: php, decimal, percentage

I've an online test result page, my code is:

```
echo ($r1['om']/$r['maxmarks']*100)." %";
```

Result showing: 61.764705882353 %

How to setup 61.76 % instead?

Comment: And the implementation language is?

Comment: php coding used

Comment: You might want to tag the question with that: many folk listen on a tag basis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

`echo number_format($r1['om']/$r['maxmarks']*100,2)`

Comment: Adding to this, note that number_format will round for you too. For free! That is probably what you'd want...

Comment: Thanks Amab Hore, appreciated for the help indeed