# Set precision for floats in php for 15 numbers after comma

Tags: php, floating-point, numbers, precision, floating-accuracy

Servus,
I have a problem with float numbers in PHP. My number is

```
$cosVQ = 0.907424504992097
```

but when I do some math operations `$cosVQ`, I will receive different results in  Javascript and PHP. Or for example wen I do echo I will receive only `0.9074245049920`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found answer for my question, which works as I wanted: `ini_set('precision', 15);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`number_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format($cosVQ, 15);
```

Comment: I would like to do more math with those variables, and number_format returns only string