# How to round money in Twig to save zero in the end?

Tags: php, twig

For example I have `19.796` and I need to round it up  so I use it like this `{% set final_sum = sum + (sum / 100 * 21) | number_format(2, 'ceil') %}` and it returns me `19.8` but I need `19.80` with zero on the end.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483561/2815635

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Did you mean $price = 19.796;  echo $price = number_format(round($price, 2), 2);

Comment: The main problem is that I need to do this in twig.

Comment: Guys, this question about twig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
{{ "%.2f"|format(final_sum) }}
```

or [localized currency](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html#localizedcurrency):

```
{{ final_sum|localizedcurrency('EUR') }}
```

**UPD:**

in your case you can do something like that:

```
{% set final_sum = "%.2f" | format(sum + (sum / 100 * 21)) %}
```

So then you just can use this already formatted value as `{{ final_sum }}`

Comment: Is it possible to use it with `set` as i need to use `final_sum` in many places

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `number_format` is [decimal point](http://php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php)
I don't know `twig` but a look in the [docs](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html) tell me that you should try this code

```
{% set final_sum = ceil(sum + (sum / 100 * 21))|number_format(2) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ '%.2f'|format(19.796) }}
```

it will round it to 19.80

Answer (score 0):

use this.

{{ "%.2f"|format(19.796|round(2, 'ceil')) }} //19.80

19.8 is same as 19.80 so if you want with trailing 0 then convert it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ "%.2f"|format(19.796) }}
```

as a very basic approach... :)
prints out
    19.80