# decimal number formatting issue

Tags: php, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am facing a problem in formatting the decimal number, Suppose i can have two decimal number in which decimal can be before or after 18th digits,  format like:

```
$num1 = 12345678912345678912345.52458

$num2 = 123.54893256666666
```

for above two number my desired out is base on condition that is

**for $num1:** 
if decimal comes after 18th digit so the decimal should be just after 18digit and after that 2 digit comes as a precision only

**for $num2:**
if decimal comes before 18th digit so the decimal should be as it is position but the precision should be only 2 digit after decimal

desired out:

```
$num1 = 123456789123456789.00
$num2 = 123.54
```

I have tried this with number `number_format()` like below:

```
<?php
    $num1 = 12345678912345678912345.52458;
    $num2 = 123.54893256666666;
    $num1 = number_format($num1,2,'.',''); //it is not working
    $num2 = number_format($num2,2,'.',''); //it is working
    echo $num1."<br>".$num2;
```

> output:

```
for $num1 = 12345678912345679593472.00 where it should comes like 123456789123456789.00

for $num1 = 123.55 that is ok
```

please help i am not getting how to use `number_format()` for $num1

Comment: PHP can't handle numbers that are that big. Do a `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` and see what the max size is on your system (it differs depending on if you use 32- or 64bit version).

Comment: but my number is decimal ? will `PHP_INT_MAX` work

Comment: Yes. Numbers are numbers. Otherwise it wouldn't be an issue if you just needed to add a `.0` after a too large integer.

Comment: it give me the result 2147483647

Comment: Then you're running 32 bit version of PHP and that is the largest number it can handle. Why do you need a number that big, to start with? Where does it come from and what are you trying to do?

Comment: actually i am handling  and made a check for input field data that can be enter

Answer (score 0):

Why you need that large number?
by default php supports 14 digits. for example

```
$num = 12345678122222;
if (strpos($num, '.') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}else
    echo 'false';
```

If you write that code, it will echo false that is correct but if you add one more digit to $num then php will not handle it properly.

And for you two digit after decimal. See this link
it is already answered

[PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: The max size of an integer in PHP isn't always the same. It depends on if you're running 32-. or 64 bit version of PHP. The OP's number is too large even for 64 bit systems, though.

Comment: yes you are right. But i'm having 64 bit OS and currently its working with only 14 digits.

Comment: Sure, but you need to have the 64 bit version of PHP as well.