# How I set two decimal place in php?

Tags: php

I want to set two decimal place. I have two numbers, one is 45 and other is 6.5. Now I want to print it like 45.00 and 6.50
I use php. 
Can any one help me?

My code is given below

```
<?php 
$a=45; $b=6.5;
echo ($a,2); echo ($b,2);
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483561/4248328

Comment: use php `number_format()` function for this like `number_format($a,2)`

Comment: you can also use `sprintf("%.2f",$a)` to show a number to two decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [number_format](http://php.net/number-format) function:

```
$a = 45;
echo number_format($a, 2);
// prints out "45.00"
```

Comment: $b=6.5 ; echo number_format($b,2); // print out "6.50" possible?

Comment: Correct. Check out the link to the official PHP documentation for number_format, it goes into detail about all of the different ways the function can be used to format numbers.