# Increase price by 20%

Tags: php

I have my php code, which increases the value by 20% however. Its format isn't well, price friendly.
It's giving a 3 figure number after the decimal point rather a 2 figure number.
Here is my code:

```html
$percentageChange = 20.00;
$sum_total = '1460.46';
//Our original number.
 
//Get 2.25% of 100.
$numberToAdd = ($sum_total / 100) * $percentageChange;
 
//Finish it up with some simple addition
$total_price = $sum_total + $numberToAdd;
 
   
echo $total_price;
```

Comment: A side note, `$total_price = $sum_total * 1.2;` seems easier.

Comment: Also as a side note, don't bother creating a snippet for non-js/html/css question, because we can't run the code :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a function called [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) this will allow you to format a number to what you want.

Comment: Thank you, thats just what I needed. I'll mark this as the answer in 9 minuets when It lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can round to 2 decimals:

```
$total_price=round($total_price,2);
```