# How to format a decimal number based on certain values in php

Tags: php, decimal, number-formatting

I am having few values
99.00
99.90
99.01

FYI, I am already getting the above 3 values after having number_format($value, 2) applied to them

But now I want to strip the decimals without rounding them off such as
99.00 to 99
99.90 to 99.9
99.01 to 99.01 remains same

How can achieve this? Please devise me a way guys.

I just need a function which checks following:

1. Whether a given number is decimal i.e having "." and digits after decimal
2. Whether the last digit is 0, if yes, then get rid of the last digit
3. Whether both the digits after decimal points are 0, if yes, remove them.
4. If any of them are not 0, then they should remain there, like in case of 99.09 it should remain intact, in case of 99.90 it should be 99.9.

Awaiting your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `round()` instead of `number_format()`?

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please mark my answer as accepted :)

Comment: Hard choice, there are three decent answers and ways to do it ;)

Comment: I updated mine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 3):

By adding `0` to the number, the rightmost zeros are removed:

```
$num1 = 99.00;
$num2 = 99.90;
$num3 = 99.01;
$num4 = 99.012;
$num5 = 99.0123;

$num1 = number_format(99.00,   2, '.', '') + 0;
$num2 = number_format(99.90,   2, '.', '') + 0;
$num3 = number_format(99.01,   2, '.', '') + 0;
$num4 = number_format(99.012,  2, '.', '') + 0;
$num5 = number_format(99.0123, 2, '.', '') + 0;

echo "$num1\n";
echo "$num2\n";
echo "$num3\n";
echo "$num4\n";
echo "$num5\n";
```

Output:

```
99
99.9
99.01
99.01
99.01
```

Try it [here](https://eval.in/942638).

**With a `function`**:

```
function round2no0(&$num)
{
    $num = number_format($num, 2, '.', '') + 0;
}
```

usage:

```
$num1 = 99.00;
$num2 = 99.90;
$num3 = 99.01;
$num4 = 99.012;
$num5 = 99.0123;

round2no0($num1);
round2no0($num2);
round2no0($num3);
round2no0($num4);
round2no0($num5);

echo "$num1\n";
echo "$num2\n";
echo "$num3\n";
echo "$num4\n";
echo "$num5\n";

function round2no0(&$num)
{
    $num = number_format($num, 2, '.', '') + 0;
}
```

Output:

```
99
99.9
99.01
99.01
99.01
```

**Edit:**

Added `, '.', ''` parameters to `number_format` to handle also numbers with thousands maintaining the machine-format `12345.12`.

Try it [here](https://eval.in/942644).

Comment: Your example is correct only if the desired result is with max 2 decimals.

Comment: @PramodKharade, the aim of your comment here?!?

Comment: I tried the above but there is issue with certain values such as

<?php
$num1 = number_format(floatval("1,200.00"),   2) + 0;
$num2 = number_format(1200.00,   2) + 0;
$num3 = number_format(99.11,   2) + 0;
$num4 = number_format(99.00,  2) + 0;
$num5 = number_format(99.000, 2) + 0;

echo "$num1\n";
echo "$num2\n";
echo "$num3\n";  
echo "$num4\n";  
echo "$num5\n";  
?>

1
1
99.11
99
99

Notice that num1 and num2 are returning as 1 whereas I need it as 1,200

Comment: @Asnexplore see my edit: now it handles correctly also numbers with tousands.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to just wrap it in a `floatval()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo round(99.001, 2), PHP_EOL;
echo round(99.901, 2), PHP_EOL;
echo round(99.011, 2), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
99
99.9
99.01
```

Comment: `number_format` rounds as well so I think Asnexplore was ok with it rounding. Your answer is the cleanest solution (all he needs is that, nothing more), no idea why the downvote.

Comment: @IncredibleHat You are right, he does do a rounding already so I removed the extra stuff I added.

Comment: Yes, true the rounding etc. was all done. I need these results post that to cleanup the trailing 0 or 0s.

Comment: Try with numbers like 1200.91, 1,200.00, 1,200.90, 1,200.
They are showing as 1 if the comma is not there, but with commas they are generating an error message
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /tmp/execpad-edf220d84a3a/source-edf220d84a3a on line 2

Comment: Though I appreciate your hard work in helping me, unfortunately, it's still not doing what I wanted to have.

Comment: That's because everything after the comma is ignored. Don't use commas, numbers don't have commas, you are using strings. The input should be number `1200.90` and not the string `1,200.90`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom notation with [`number_format`](https://secure.php.net/number_format), you can use [`preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/preg_replace) to remove the decimal point separator and trailing zeroes after it.

```
// Default notation
echo preg_replace('/\.?0+$/', '', number_format(9990.00, 2)); // "9,990"
echo preg_replace('/\.?0+$/', '', number_format(9990.90, 2)); // "9,990.9"
echo preg_replace('/\.?0+$/', '', number_format(9990.01, 2)); // "9,990.01"

// French notation
echo preg_replace('/,?0+$/', '', number_format(9990.00, 2, ',', ' ')); // "9 990"
echo preg_replace('/,?0+$/', '', number_format(9990.90, 2, ',', ' ')); // "9 990,9"
echo preg_replace('/,?0+$/', '', number_format(9990.01, 2, ',', ' ')); // "9 990,01"
```