# Round to 2 decimal places calling data from json - php

Tags: php, html, json, math

```
foreach($arrayUsers as $user) {
echo '<tr><td>'. $user['firstname'] .'</td><td>'. $user['lastname'] .'</td><td>'. $currencies[$user["currency"]] . $user['salary']. 
    '</td></tr>';
}
?>
```

Calling 'salary' from a JSON file, but need this to be rounded to 2 decimal places in the output table.

Comment: Look into `number_format`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rounding numbers you can use the `round()` and you can mention the precision as well.

```
round($user['salary'], 2)
```

You can find more information on round function [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Hope this helps.