# Number of output decimal places

Tags: php

I made a code for calculating Woocommmerce discount...
Sorry for the stupid question, but I can not find a solution.

"division" outputs the "price_per_bottle" devided by "price_per_ltr".
I can not get it to output only 2 decimal places ("12.30" as in €), because now, by default, there are many.

```
<button id='add' type='button' onclick='ik(this.value);'  value='3'>
30% Discount <span class="kalkc3" id="kalk1"><?php 
$price_per_bottle= $product->get_price();
$price_per_ltr= 0.7; 
$division = $price_per_bottle/ $price_per_ltr; 
echo $division;
?></span></button>
```

I have found the answer, but not in the mentioned post... But with trial and error:)..

```
<?php 
$kokstane3 = $product->get_price(); 
$popust3 = 0.7; 
$rezultat3 = $kokstane3 * $popust3;
echo (round($rezultat3,2));// <= HERE
?>
```

Comment: echo round($division, 2);

Comment: note - `round()` will not work, if you have thousands seperator

Comment: in which case - you should go with `number_format` like the answer explains

Comment: I highly recommend not to ever use non-English identifiers when programming.

Comment: This question appears to be related to PHP, not Javascript/jQuery. Edited the tags.

Comment: I found the answer, but, not in the mentioned post... But by trial and error:)

<button class="add3" id='add3' type='button' onclick='ik(this.value); add3f()'  value='3'>
30% Popusta <span class="kalkc3" id="kalk1"><?php 
$kokstane3 = $product->get_price(); // <= HERE
$popust3 = 0.7; 
$rezultat3 = $kokstane3 * $popust3;
echo (round($rezultat3,2));
?>

Comment: The solution from the edit is in the linked post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338830/466862, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483553/466862 You should not only look at the accepted answer, but also at the other (upvoted) answers. An accepted answer is not necessarily the only (nor the best) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format)

```
$flaschenpreis = $product->get_price();
$literpreis = 0.7; 
$division = $flaschenpreis / $literpreis; 

$division = number_format((float)$division , 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: I am unable to use this... Output is "non existent"

Comment: It works! Please check here(http://phptester.net/)