# Remove comma from number format without removing decimal point in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code to give `$value` a number format:

```
    $value=1000000.00;

    number_format($value,2);

    echo str_replace(",", "", $value)
```

But when I try to replace the comma, the decimals get removed. I want to print `$value` as it originally was: `1000000.00`. How can I do that?

Comment: you can tell [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) what it should use as decimal-seperator! No need for the str_replace

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places/4483561#4483561 (cannot vote due to retracted previous vote)

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone yes and no. the real issue here was the failure to assign the output of `number_format`.

Comment: @Nick the question is how to properly achieve the intended result, the duplicate actually answers this.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone fair enough. done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to assign the output of [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to the variable:

```
$value=1000000.00;
$value = number_format($value,2);
echo str_replace(",", "", $value);
```

Output:

```
1000000.00
```

You can also simply  tell `number_format` not to use a thousands separator:

```
$value = number_format($value,2,'.','');
echo $value;
```

Output:

```
1000000.00
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iGk1r)

Answer (score 4):

You can tell [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) what it should use as decimal-point and thousands-seperator! No need for the str_replace:

```
$value = 1000000.00;
echo number_format($value, 2, ".", "");
// output:
// 1000000.00
```