# method giving price as a string, and not a float

Tags: php

I am returning JSON from this array, but the value of `total` is in string format - not a float. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

This is the array, which ends up having a string:

```
return [ 
    'cart' => [
        'total'  => amount($cart->total)
    ]
]
```

And this is the `amount` helper method, where the issue is coming from:

```
function amount($money)
{
    return number_format(floatval($money), 2);
}
```

I am expecting a float back from `total`, not a string.

Comment: If you question has been answered, accepting an answer with the check mark can help others find an answer in the future and aid the rest of the community in focusing efforts.

Answer (score 5):

[`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) returns a string.

In your case, you might be passing a value such as `3.15` in which case a string would seem to be an odd output. But, if you passed a value like `311583249` you would see why this is the case: `number_format(311583249)` returns `"311,583,249"`.

It returns a string every time for continuity. If it returned an integer when there's a whole number less than 1,000, or a a float when there's a partial number less than 1,000, then that would be more difficult to account for overall and not serve the exact purpose that `number_format` has - so a string is always returned by `number_format`.

What you might be looking for instead would be [`round(X, 2)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php); this would return a float with the precision of 2. Or maybe you're looking for [`money_format('%i', X)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) - this also returns a string but formatted as if it were money.

Answer (score -1):

That's normal. In this case, if you break down the types of everything you're executing like so:

```
var_dump(1000000.12);
var_dump(floatval(1000000.12));
var_dump(number_format(floatval(1000000.12), 2));
```

Then you will notice that `number_format` is the point at which it becomes a string, given the comma delimitation:

```
float(1000000.12)
float(1000000.12)
string(12) "1,000,000.12"
```

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places) may be useful for you as an alternative approach.

Comment: thank you both!  However, this still happens for numbers less than 999 (no comma).  It would be returned as "999"

Comment: @burtonLowel That is correct, it only returns strings. It doesn't make a lot of sense other than continuity for whole numbers under 1,000, but that is why.