# how to set the min and max to 2 decimal places in php

Tags: php, set, max, min

```
<?php
$result = array_filter($_POST);    
if(!empty($result)){
echo ((max($result)+min($result))/2)*1.2 ."|".((max($result)+min($result))/2)*1.3;
}
?>
```

hi all..how to set min and max result to 2 decimals places for the code above? actually the result will appears in input type text after the process complete

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 2):

Use `number_format` function in PHP.

> number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] ) : string
>    
> For more information see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php)

```
$yourNumber = 1235.343;

echo number_format ($yourNumber, 2);

// Will output 1,235.34 (with two decimals, specified in number_format as second paramter.
```

**Edit:** Max / Min functions return mixed value. Make sure its `float` and then pass it to `number_format`. It will returns you the `string`.