# Percentage Formatter

Tags: php

I'm using this

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::PERCENT);
print $formatter->format(.45);
Result = 45%
```

How to change to 45.00% (show 2 decimal place)

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places)

Comment: hello and thank you @IvMisticos, i'm already look the link but still no match for answer that i look and because the documentation for NumberFormatter is so little hope someone know can help me