# Add custom order meta data with price exluding tax in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I'm trying to create a custom `meta_key` in `woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table for (unit price excluding tax) to use later.

I added the below code but I keep getting an error on the checkout page, showing only the red mark with '`Internal Server Error`'.

Someone who knows where things are going wrong?

```php
// Save custom data to order item meta data

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'unit_price_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
function unit_price_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

        $unit_price  =  wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product );

        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_unit_price', $unit_price , false );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you use `$product` while this is not specified anywhere.

Note: `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` hook is [deprecated](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-deprecated-functions.php#L625-L631) since WooCommerce 3. Use [`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0f134ca6a20c8132be490b22ad8d1dc245d81cc0/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L489) instead

So replace:

```
// Save custom data to order item meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'unit_price_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
function unit_price_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

    $unit_price  =  wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product );

    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_unit_price', $unit_price , false );

}
```

With

```
function action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    // The WC_Product instance Object
    $product = $item->get_product();
    
    $unit_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product );
        
    $item->update_meta_data( '_unit_price', $unit_price );
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Its working great but the unit price shows as 15.658174. Is there a way to make in 15.66.

Comment: Before you assign `$unit_price` to the `meta_data` you can use a rounding function, see [Show a number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places). Regards

Comment: I add this // $unit_price_value = number_format( $unit_price , 2 ); // and changed last line to $unit_price_value and its working