# How can I show up to 2 decimal points

Tags: laravel, decimal, laravel-blade

I am making a ecommerce website in laravel 6.20 and in the product view page I wanted to show the discount at a percantage rate. I could show a round figure but I want to show the percentage at a 2 decimal point format. any help will be appreciated.

```
<ul class="product_marks">
    @if($row->discount_price == NULL)
    @else
       <li class="product_mark product_discount">
       -{{round(($row->discount_price/$row->selling_price)*100)}}%
       </li>
    @endif
    <li class="product_mark product_new">NEW</li>
</ul>
```

[Please check this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBRxL.png)

Comment: Could you tag your question with the languages/libraries you are using. It would help people who know the correct environment come to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `number_format($number, $decimal_points)` to define number of decimal points you want:

```
-{{number_format(round(($row->discount_price/$row->selling_price)*100), 2)}}%
```