# How to convert number to float in PHP

Tags: php, numbers

**I need to convert both int and float to float, not string.**

I tried to convert the number to float with `floatval` function.

But `floatval(int)` returns `int`.

For example:

`floatval(100)` returns `100`

I need to get `100.00`

**What is the solution?**

Comment: If you want the .00, this is more about formatting than storage internally of the value.

Comment: @NigelRen. Thanks for your comment. As you said, If this problem is related to formatting, it returns a string. it's not `float`.
if I convert string to float, it returns int or float.
What do you think about that?

Comment: `number_format` would be a good function to look at for formatting

Comment: @hppycoder. Good answer. thanks. but not perfect. Android requires the exact data type. `number_format` returns `string`, it is not `float`

Comment: Are you asking why the language doesn't natively hold the decimal places on an integer?

Comment: More information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places

Comment: I would wager that you are misunderstand how values are passed over HTTP to your Android app, and the handling within that app is at fault, not anything particularly to do with PHP. You should post a new question with code from both sides, and we might be able to give you more pertinent advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use number_format function to format the numbers for desired output.

```
$foo = "105.01";
$zoo = "105";
echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', ''); //Output 105.01
echo number_format((float)$zoo, 2, '.', ''); //Output 105.00
```

Comment: maybe, need to get it as a string, then parse the string to float on the front side.