# How to Convert Number to always have 2 digits after the decimal?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Quick question: I am trying to always get 2 digits after the money amount I previously had this code:

```
case 'tool_paid':
      echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'tool_paid', true );
      break;
```

But it only returns me 650 and I want it to return 650.00 I have tried the following with no success:

```
case 'tool_paid':
      $toolpaid = get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'tool_paid', true );
      echo $toolpaid number_format(2);
      break;
```

Thanks for any help on this, still a noob at php.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
case 'tool_paid':
      $toolpaid = get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'tool_paid', true );
      echo number_format($toolpaid,2);  // Corrected syntax & parameters here.
      break;
```

PHP will coerce the variable to `float` as required, unless `declare(strict_types=1)`, in which case it will fail with a `TypeError`. You can coerce the number if need be with simple cast.

For example:

`echo number_format((float)$toolpaid,2);`

The [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is a good place to look for function parameters and syntax.

Demo:https://3v4l.org/MpFMi

Comment: Thanks but this throws me an error of `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in C:\Users\...\wp-content\themes\custom-theme\custom\admincolumns.php on line 70` Also see code line [here](https://prnt.sc/1vx5gbw)

Comment: Then something else is wrong. If you provide a number as a string (e.g. `"650"`) then PHP will coerce it as required. This works for all supported versions and at least as far back as PHP 5.6. See the demo I've linked to

Comment: Whoops, My dump show that number coming over as a string: `...theme\vendor\twig\twig\src\Extension\DebugExtension.php:61:string '650' (length=3)` what would I need to do to convert that? - Would you mind updating the code example?

Comment: You might have `declare(strict_types=1)` set. I've update my answer and the demo.

Comment: That works: `echo number_format((float)$toolpaid,2);` ~Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ShrockCo If this works for you, please accept the answer. Click the tick next to the answer.

Comment: One more question? If I decided to add a $ before the number such as $650.00 what would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: You could just prepend the currency symbol with `'$'.number_format(...)`, or you could use `sprintf()` to format the number and add the symbol at the same time. There are other ways.