# number_format not showing up as a number

Tags: php

PHP number_format not showing up as a number.
I should display as number instead of string.

```
$calc = "500020.66000000";
$calc = number_format((float)$calc, 2, '.', '');
$return_data =
   [
       'data' => [
           'balance' => number_format((float)$calc, 2, '.', ''),
       ],
   ];
```

return

```
{
    "data": {
        "balance": "500020.66",
        "currency": "TRY"
    }
}
```

must be

```
{
    "data": {
        "balance": 500020.66,
        "currency": "TRY"
    }
}
```

Fixed:
php.ini add

```
serialize_precision=-1
```

```
round($calc,2);
```

Comment: `number_format` returns a string, because only a string can have *format*. A number only has a *value*, not particular *formatting*.

Comment: Rather than trying to adjust this misunderstood attempt.  Let's focus on what your desired out is. Do you want to round up or down to two decimal places? Do you want a [`bc` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775538/2943403)?

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look into the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) you will see that `number_format` returns a string:

```
 number_format(
    float $num,
    int $decimals = 0,
    ?string $decimal_separator = ".",
    ?string $thousands_separator = ","
): string
```

BTW: It doesn't make sence to return a formatted number in a json

Comment: yes but requested number :/

Comment: try `'balance' => (float)$calc`

Comment: return 500020.6599999999743886291980743408203125
should be 2 decimals: 500020.66

Comment: `(float)number_format((float)$calc, 2, '.', '')`

Comment: not working 500082.640000000013969838619232177734375

Comment: `(double)number_format((float)$calc, 2, '.', ''),` works for me

Comment: :) not working : 500020.6599999999743886291980743408203125

Comment: Also `$calc = "500020.66000000";
$return_data =
   [
       'data' => [
           'balance' => (double)$calc,
       ],
   ];

echo json_encode($return_data)
` is working fine for me (php -f x.php
{"data":{"balance":500020.66}}

Comment: @ege You can't have both a specific formatting for the number, but also have it be a float, unless you cobble together the entire JSON string by hand so you can treat the number as a string in the process. Why is it so important to have exactly two decimal places?!