# How to format a decimal number from a json object in PHP?

Tags: php, json, rounding

I'm trying to format a decimal number that I've optained from a json object in PHP. My objective is to keep this number with just two places after the comma.

Here is the code:

`

```
$url = "https://api.yadio.io/exrates/EUR";
$data =  json_decode(file_get_contents($url, true));
$object = $data;
foreach($object as $a){
echo round($a->CUP, 2);
}
```

`

The result without `round()` was `163.905765`, so when I apply it, the result is `0163.9100` and should be `163.90`.

Any help will be very appretiate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json response is of type -

```
{
"BTC": 20849.71,
"EUR": {
"CAD": 1.353201,
"CDF": 2030.444751,
"CHF": 0.990328,
"CLP": 939.150233,
"CNY": 7.204403,
"COP": 4731.844098,
"CRC": 617.225833,
"CUP": 163.905765,
},
"base": "EUR",
"timestamp": 1666977603763
}
```

So you are not looping around it correctly.

try this -

```
$url = "https://api.yadio.io/exrates/EUR";
$data =  json_decode(file_get_contents($url, true));
$object = $data;
echo round($object->EUR->CUP,2);
```