# How to format a number to 2 decimal places in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, format, decimal, laravel-blade

I want to format a double value returned from db to 2 decimal places

I tried number_format($amount,2) but it didn't work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? With some test code, like `$amount = (double)2;` followed by `number_format($amount, 2)`, I get `"2.00"`, which looks correct to me... What is happening in your code?

Comment: "Didn't work" is not an adequate description of the issue. What was the result? What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Use the php number_format

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
```

1. 2 decimal places.
2. '.' for decimal separator
3. ',' for thousand separator

Answer (score 0):

Try and explicitly cast the double value to float like mentioned in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-two-decimal-places)

Also, check what type is the $amount variable in your example..